# Django: Include template with variables rendered from views.py into another template

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a template `plot.html` inside app `plot`:

```
<div>
{{ plot|safe }}
</div>
some other divs here
```

The plot variable is calculated from `views.py` inside app plot:

```
class RenderView(TemplateView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.template_name = "plot.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RenderView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['plot'] = PlotView().make_plot()
        return context
```

Now I want to include this template with the generated plot and other divs into another template from another app, another.html:

```
{% include "plot.html" %}
```

of course this does not generate the plot and other info from the views.py file.

I've been reading about template tags (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/), but I'm unsure what goes into poll_extras.py there or if tags is the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the variable with it.

```
{% include "plot.html" with plot=plot only %}
```

But you will need to pass it in from the calling `view` otherwise you might want to go for a tag.

(The `only` prevents you from copying the entire `context` to the other template)

Comment: so inside another.py import the plot module and create the plot variable to pass it the template? is it better like that then creating a tag?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga it depends on your use case. Is this the only place you will use it?

Comment: I might need to use it in other places.. I'm unsure what goes inside a custom template tag and couldn't find an example in their docs..

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga in the docs there the examples are simple but you don't really need much more. Do you need to pass `args` to get the plot? If not I would pass it with the `context` from the `view` itself.

Comment: I managed to create my templatetag and returned the plots and divs there. But if I will make a change and add a new plot, then I'll have to make my change twice, once in template.html and once in templatetag. I was expecting that I should make my change only once in template.html...

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga I really don't know enough about your use case. I am in the office all day (EU time), feel free to send me a chat invite.